# Windows makefile - invalid switch and and unrecognized environmental variables

Tags: windows, cmd, makefile, environment-variables

So I recently overtook an old project and the person originally responsible for the project left the company, so sadly there is no one to ask. Basically, the project is an environment generator, originally written in a bunch of batch files and then reworked as a python project. Sadly, there is also very limited documentation and I do not have a lot of developing experience on windows.

So yeah the OS is Windows 10, python version 3.8.

My issue is as follows:

At some point the env-generator calls a makefile generator (originally developed by another company and again the person responsible is no longer there). The generated makefile contains the following lines (and a lot more similar ones):

```
.PHONY: pycharm
pycharm:
    cmd /c start /B $(PKG_pyCharm_ce_2019_1)/bin/pycharm64.exe .
```

And it works fine if the environment is generated using the original bat-file based generator. However, with the "new" env-generator, I can no longer run the makefile, although I am using the same version of make (GNU Make 4.1 - Built for Windows32).

Basically, I have two issues. First I get the error `Invalid switch - "/bin".` and secondly it does not resolve the environmental variable (i.e. I end up with `\bin\pycharm64.exe` instead of  `C:\devapp\ipm\p\pyCharm_ce_2019_1\0.0.2\data\bin\pycharm64.exe`).

If I change the line by hand to:

```
.PHONY: pycharm
pycharm:
    cmd /c start /B %PKG_pyCharm_ce_2019_1%\bin\pycharm64.exe .
```

it works fine. What could be the reason that it works differently?
I have checked that the PATH and other used environmental variables are the same.
If I run the commands directly from the shell

```
cmd /c start /B C:\devapp\ipm\p\pyCharm_ce_2019_1\0.0.2\data/bin/pycharm64.exe . 
and
cmd /c start /B %PKG_pyCharm_ce_2019_1%/bin/pycharm64.exe .
```

work fine,

```
cmd /c start /B $(ISC_IPM_PKG_pyCharm_ce_2019_1)/bin/pycharm64.exe .
```

doesn't (Windows cannot find $(ISC_IPM_PKG_pyCharm_ce_2019_1)/bin/pycharm64.exe).

Why is this? And what do can I change in my environment to make the first lines work?

Sadly, I cannot change the makefile generator, and changing the lines manually (or via script) does not really scale to the usage scenario.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the code but it sounds like your new env generator isn't setting `PKG_pyCharm_ce_2019_1` correctly (or at all).  You can add a check to your `makefile` with something like `$(info PKG_pyCharm_ce_2019_1=[$(PKG_pyCharm_ce_2019_1)])` .

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I think with this I discovered the reason. The new tool uses pythons os.environ to set env vars, however it makes all the env vars upper case. So replacing `PKG_pyCharm_ce_2019_1` with `PKG_PYCHARM_CE_2019_1` in the makefile worked. But why does `%PKG_pyCharm_ce_2019_1%` work then? And shouldn't windows env vars be case insensitive?

Comment: If you use `$(VAR)` the variable is expanded by Make. Make variable names are case sensitive. If you use `%VAR%` the variable is expanded by Windows. Windows environment variable names are case insensitive.